# How to write JavaScript form validation regex

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

I'm really new to HTML and JavaScript and I'm working on using regex to validate input...

I used `/^[a-z]+$/i`.test (firstName) to make sure the entered first name was all characters.

if`( /^\d{8}$/.test(idNum))` doesn't seem to be working. I'm trying to make sure they enter an 8 digit number.

I've got to validate some other fields like Address, city, state, zip and phone number. Any resources or examples would be great!

Thanks!

Comment: both should work. What's wrong with that?

Comment: Top one works fine, second one evaluates as false every time, even when I enter valid input

Comment: Check this link - http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html

Comment: Have you been visited http://regex101.com/ ? It may helps you.

Comment: @Sean I just tried this - `/^\d{8}$/.test('88888889')` and it works fine. What is the input you are passing ? I hope it is same as mine

Comment: oh duh. I got my value from a form and forgot to add .value to the end..

Comment: Thank you for your help! 

I'm trying to figure out how to validate the address and phone number now, thank you for those links I hope they help! I've been having little luck googling.

Comment: How would I go about validating a street address?   I'd need to make sure it had a number, then a space, then alphabetic chars and/or numbers for the street... Seems really complicated

Comment: Is `^[0-9]+ [a-zA-Z0-9]+$` enough? https://regex101.com/r/fI8bM8/1. Please use only 1 question per post. And formulate clear requirements to get a prompt and good answer.